# Módulo JavaScript bloqueado por MIME no permitido

Tags: javascript, html, express

Intentando realizar imports y exports entre ficheros de JavaScript que se encuentra en un servidor local de express.js me he topado con el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He leído documentación al respecto sobre los MIME y cómo poder cambiarlos en el atributo `enctype` de la etiqueta html `form` pero no he conseguido ninguna solución.

El problema resalta el siguiente fichero: mathFunctions

```
export const MATH_PATTERN = /(\d+(-)+\d)/;;
export function math() {

    let result;
    //pattern = /(\d+(-)+\d)/;
    let numbers = input.split('-');

    let a = numbers[0];
    let b = numbers[1];

    result = `

        Neperiano:            ${(Math.log(a))}  
        Raíz:                 ${(Math.sqrt(a))}
        Elevado:              ${(Math.pow(a,b))}
        Más cercano y menor:  ${(Math.floor(a))}
        Más cercano y mayor:  ${(Math.ceil(b))}
        Redondeo:             ${(Math.round(a))}
        Número random (0-1):  ${(Math.random())}  Número random (a-b): ${(Math.random(a * b))}
        Seno:                 ${(Math.sin(b))}
        Coseno:               ${(Math.cos(b))}
        Tangente:             ${(Math.tan(b))}
        Absoluto:             ${(Math.abs(a))}
        Valor máximo:         ${(Math.max(a,b))}
        Valor mínimo:         ${(Math.min(a,b))}
        -----------------------------------------
        Hipotenusa:           ${(Math.hypot(a,b))}

        `;

        return (result);

}
```

main js:

```
import {checkPattern} from './js/verificationFunctions.js';
import {math, MATH_PATTERN} from './js/mathFunctions';

function resquestData() {

    let input = prompt("INTRODUCIR NÚMERO A-B: ");

    if(checkPattern(input, MATH_PATTERN) == true) {
        math();
    }
    else {
        alert("PATRON INTRODUCIDO INCORRECTO");
    }
}
```

El fichero HTML es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body> 
    <form action="" enctype="">
        <button onclick= " getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = `<textarea rows=20 cols=80> ${(resquestData())} </textarea> `"> Realizar Operaciones </button>
    </form>

    <div id="textarea"></div>

    <script type="module" src="../main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Agradecería cualquier tipo de documentación relacionada con express, JavaScript o ayuda; muchas gracias.

Comment: Que tienes en `main.js`?

Comment: Post actualizado, aún no está el código terminado ya que me da error de que la función no está definida, pero eso ya es otro error aparte.

Comment: No se si será el problema, pero debes poner el `.js` en el import cuando lo ejecutará un navegador `./js/mathFunctions.js`.

Comment: Muchas gracias un pequeño despiste en la sintaxis, que me daba un error un poco confuso.